# LaTeX document compiles, but tikzpicture is not showing up

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm currently in the middle of moving a large LaTeX document from one layout to another. I have problems with this tikzpicture figure, which does not appear in the final PDF even though LaTeX compiles without any issues:

```
% **************************************************
\documentclass[
    paper=A4,               % paper size
    twoside=true,           % onesite or twoside printing
    openright,              % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
    parskip=full,           % spacing value / method for paragraphs
    chapterprefix=true,     % prefix for chapter marks
    11pt,                   % font size
    headings=normal,        % size of headings
    bibliography=totoc,     % include bib in toc
    listof=totoc,           % include listof entries in toc
    titlepage=on,           % own page for each title page
    captions=tableabove,    % display table captions above the float env
    draft=false,            % value for draft version
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,decorations,automata,backgrounds,petri,topaths,calc,mindmap,trees,positioning,chains,arrows}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}

% Gaussian plot with #1 = mean and #2 = standard deviation
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}
}

\begin{document}

\textbf{MWE} \\
Here we go...
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none,domain=-10:10,samples=100,smooth},
    enlargelimits=upper,legend style={at={(1.02,0.825)},anchor=west}] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top
    \addplot [line width=0.25mm, red,dotted] {gauss(0,1)};
    \addplot [line width=0.25mm, blue,dashed] {gauss(0,2)};
    \addplot [line width=0.25mm, green] {gauss(1,1)};
    \addplot [line width=0.25mm, orange,dashdotted] {gauss(1,2)};

    \addlegendentry{Gaussian with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$}
    \addlegendentry{Gaussian with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 2$}
    \addlegendentry{Gaussian with $\mu = 1$ and $\sigma = 1$}
    \addlegendentry{Gaussian with $\mu = 1$ and $\sigma = 2$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My label} \label{fig:MyLabel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: An MWE would be helpful in this case - don't post many code snippets, just a compilable one is enough.

Comment: Is there an error or a warning in the log file? What do you see in the output pdf, an empty space or nothing at all? Maybe the figure gets moved to the end of the chapter or document and you just overlooked it?

Comment: @Marijn I can't spot any warnings except for "underfull" or "overfull "\hbox"es. In the output pdf, I see the "Fig: My label" caption but there is just empty white space above the caption.

Comment: I just added an MWE for better debugging. Please see the updated post above.

Comment: Thanks I can confirm same here

Comment: with each additional `\addplot` the image gets shifted further right, so after 4 plots it is outside the margin (I don't know why)

Comment: This does not happen if you use the function directly in the `\addplot` macro instead of using `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`

Comment: This works fine: https://pastebin.com/dh70uLvL

Comment: @samcarter Thank you very much, this works great! The only remaining question is: Why does \pgfmathdeclarefunction produce this right shift?

Comment: @Hagbard That's something I am wondering myself. I hope that some pgf wizard will be able to solve this mystery!

Comment: @Hagbard Mystery solved :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem are missing `%` at the line ending of the function definition. The unprotected line endings are interpreted as spaces and each time you use the function in `\addplot` additional white space is inserted and the plots are pushed off the right boarder of the page

```
% **************************************************
\documentclass[
    paper=A4,               % paper size
    twoside=true,           % onesite or twoside printing
    openright,              % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
    parskip=full,           % spacing value / method for paragraphs
    chapterprefix=true,     % prefix for chapter marks
    11pt,                   % font size
    headings=normal,        % size of headings
    bibliography=totoc,     % include bib in toc
    listof=totoc,           % include listof entries in toc
    titlepage=on,           % own page for each title page
    captions=tableabove,    % display table captions above the float env
    draft=false,            % value for draft version
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,decorations,automata,backgrounds,petri,topaths,calc,mindmap,trees,positioning,chains,arrows}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}

% Gaussian plot with #1 = mean and #2 = standard deviation
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}

\textbf{MWE} \\
Here we go...
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none,domain=-10:10,samples=100,smooth},
    enlargelimits=upper,legend style={at={(1.02,0.825)},anchor=west}] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top
    \addplot [line width=0.25mm, red,dotted] {gauss(0,1)};
    \addplot [line width=0.25mm, blue,dashed] {gauss(0,2)};
    \addplot [line width=0.25mm, green] {gauss(1,1)};
    \addplot [line width=0.25mm, orange,dashdotted] {gauss(1,2)};

    \addlegendentry{Gaussian with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$}
    \addlegendentry{Gaussian with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 2$}
    \addlegendentry{Gaussian with $\mu = 1$ and $\sigma = 1$}
    \addlegendentry{Gaussian with $\mu = 1$ and $\sigma = 2$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My label} \label{fig:MyLabel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```